# How to include subfolders while zipping in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, zlib, zip

I have folder structure where i have root folder called Home.
in home folder i have 3 sub folders and 5 files. 
when i used ionic.zip i am able to zip all the files of this Home folder. But i am not able to maintain the same folder structure.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("filepath","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
if (filePaths.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (string fileURl in filePaths)
    {
        zip.AddFile(fileURl, "VisaFiles");              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ZipFile Class  System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
        string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
        string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest,true);

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    }
}
```

You will have to include System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll in references.

Comment: @Abid- How good it is to give destination path, since i need to download this file to my local machine. User should see the zipped folder on download click.